# vscode Docker debugging csharp.listRemoteProcess failed

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, .net-5

I have a .Net 5 WebApi that i want to host and debug in Docker.
when i run the docker-compose the project launches correctly.
When attaching the debugger i get following error:
`Running the contributed command csharp.listRemoteProcess failed`

my docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 as debug
ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true  
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
EXPOSE 5000/tcp
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN curl -sSL https://aka.ms/getvsdbgsh | /bin/sh /dev/stdin -v latest -l ~/vsdbg
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "watch", "run", "--project myproject.csproj"]
```

the docker-compose file

```
version: '3.4'
services: 
  server:
    build: 
      context: ./myproject
      target: debug
    ports: 
      - "5000:5000"
    container_name: myproject
    volumes:
      - ./myproject:/app
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Docker Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickRemoteProcess}",
            "pipeTransport": {
                "pipeProgram": "docker",
                "pipeArgs": [ "exec", "-i", "csharp" ],
                "debuggerPath": "/root/vsdbg/vsdbg",
                "pipeCwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
                "quoteArgs": false
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/work": "${workspaceRoot}/myproject/"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```